# Proof of convergence for a heavy-ball adaptive step-size algorithm for non-convex functions

Tags: optimization, convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am struggling with prooving convergence for an optimizer which uses adaptive step-size with heavy ball algorithm for convex and non-convex functions. In some literature, I could find a regret bound analysis/proof for convex functions and proving that the estimated gradient at t -> inf goes to zero.

Could anyone please guide me through the process of convergence proof for non-convex functions or give me literature recommendations for the same.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: We cannot really answer without having more details. What is exactly the algorithm? What are the assumptions on the function (e.g., smooth, etc.). You will also need to specify what "convergence" you want to prove. Usually in the non-convex setting once is only able to prove convergence to critical point or local minima.

Comment: @Kas : 
Thanks for the response. I will try to include more details:  
1. The algorithm is heavy ball momentum with adaptive step-size.  
 'X_(k+1) = X_k - \eta_k . \nabla(f(x_k)) + \beta(x_k - x_(k-1))   
2. The following assumptions are made: 1. The function is smooth. 2. The function is Lipschitz.   
3. The gradients are Lipschitz. I attempt to prove the convergence to a critical point or a local minima. Where the estimate of the gradients at any instance k goes to zero. i.e. E[\nabla(f(x_k))] = 0 as t -> inf.